# What is the default file association for a file with no extension?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-registry, file-types

I have a machine that somehow became infected with WEbbiNG Adware.  I managed to remove it fine, but it seems it associated itself as the default program to run files without an extension.

I have several scripts I run through an MSYS terminal (like composer) which are now displaying in Explorer's "Type" column as "Webbing". I'm fairly sure it used to just say, "File"

I already have deleted the registry key for WebbiNG in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\. and rebooted the machine, and it did not disappear.

Then I found and edited HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\. default which was "Webbing" and I changed it to "File" and now Explorer's type column displays "URL:File Protocol"

What is the default value of HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no default program for extension-less files, when you try to double click them Windows should ask you every time what you want to do with the file.

That key should simply be empty. The key needs to be there but just delete whatever contents are in it.

If you click on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` in the left hand pane in regedit you should see a key in the right hand pane called `(Default)` with a type of `REG_SZ` and the "value" column should say `(Value not set)`

Comment: deleting it worked, thanks!  Adware is irritating.